# Is there some scripture reference to dream yoga?

Tags: reference-request, sleep, meditation-visualisation

By dream yoga I mean the practices intended to attain lucid dreaming, and then using that ability to realize that the world as we know does not exists as perceived (as in a dream) so one can reach the fully awake condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends somewhat on how you define "scripture." It's important to emphasize that "scripture" to a Buddhist doesn't necessarily mean the same thing as "scripture" to a Protestant Christian, despite the similar language.

As Rabbit references there is a document titled the [Six Yogas of Nāropa](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1559392568) (ན་རོ་ཆོས་དྲུག་, *Narö chö druk*).  Naropa himself was [no small figure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naropa), at least for certain traditions, and a lot of the teachings in the Six Yogas are widely practiced among certain sects.

That, by itself, might count as a "scriptural reference" if that's what you are going for. This has been taught as stemming from the Gautama Buddha's statements about the illusory or dream-like nature of reality. It is an established document that is [well known](http://www.rigpawiki.org/index.php?title=Six_Yogas_of_Naropa).

On the other hand, as far as I can tell it isn't listed–at least commonly–as part of the [Tibetan Buddhist canon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tibetan_Buddhist_canon) or any of the other major canons. That having been said, there are a great many Buddhist texts that cover a wide variety of different practices that are not found in in those specific texts that doesn't lessen their value.

So the question comes down to what, exactly, you consider "scripture" and why you are looking to know.

Comment: Six yogas of Naropa is not a document per se, it is a set of practises that were transmitted by Naropa down to his disciples and the transmission continues till today. There are various books with commentaries but the very practice should be transmitted in person.

Answer (score -1):

Within the [Kevatta (Kevaddha) Sutta: To Kevatta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.11.0.than.html#livelihood) it is said:

> Whereas some brahmans and contemplatives, living off food given in faith, maintain themselves by wrong livelihood, by such lowly arts as:
>
> > ...
> >
> > interpreting dreams;
> >
> > ...

Given that, I do not think it is an endorsed approach within Buddhism.

Comment: The question was about lucid dreaming, not dream interpretation. I've definitely read of dream yoga as a valid part of some Tibetan traditions. No reference though, sorry. I got it via B. Alan Wallace's writings.

Comment: @Tommy I see your point. I was thinking that using dreams as a way of understanding samsara is an interpretation that dreams transitory nature is similar to the transitory nature of samsara. Maybe I am misunderstanding the way the sutta means 'interpreting'.

Comment: @Tommy Dream Yoga is a part of 6 Yogas of Naropa, try searching that